# Ruby: param is missing or the value is empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What I am trying to do is associate a 'user' with an 'activity' and once they click the 'Join' button the error it's getting is `param is missing or the value is empty: act_joins`.
The class that its communicating by is called 'act_joins' and the **controller** for **act_joins** look like this:

```
class ActJoinsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @act_join = current_user.act_joins.new(act_join_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @act_join.save!
        format.html { redirect_to user_dashboard_path, notice: 'You successfully joined the event.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @act_join }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @act_join.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private

  def act_join_params
    params.require(:act_joins).permit(:activity_id)
  end
end
```

And the form is

`<%= form_for :act_joins, url: act_joins_path do |f| %>
  <%= f.submit 'Join', class: 'btn btn-success' %>
<% end %>`

If I am in the rails console and write: `ActJoin.create!(user_id: User.last.id, activity_id: Activity.last.id)` it works.

I seen errors like this while searching for a answer, but all the other errors had parameters coming through, but with mine its only the ID's really.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `act_join` and not `act_joins` so your statement should be:

```
params.require(:act_join).permit(:activity_id)
```

params.require takes a key name of an object which should be singular.

**Update**

Looks like you also have the key in your form_for plural. That should be `act_join` as well:

```
<%= form_for :act_join, url: act_joins_path do |f| %>
```

Comment: When I tried that I got the same error `param is missing or the value is empty: act_join`

Comment: @BelalKamara Let me know if my updated response fixes your issue

Answer (score 0):

You are not actually posting any data. 
Try adding a hidden field to the form like:

```
<%= f.hidden_field(:activity_id, value: however_you_get_your_activity_id) %>
```

Obviously substitute `however_you_get_your_activity_id` with a valid id.

For Example if we have a collection of `Activity` objects as `@activities` you could do something like:

```
<% @activities.each do |activity| %> 
  <%= form_for :act_joins, url: act_joins_path do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field(:activity_id, value: activity.id %>
    <%= f.submit 'Join', class: 'btn btn-success' %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```